# Setting up Mock repository with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am unit testing controller logic with xUnit and Moq.  I am trying to use a Mock repository object which will enable the test case to pass.  However, in my setup it caused the test to fail because the Mock repository returns `null` instead of a `TweetDay` object.

I am testing the TweetsController:

```
public class TweetsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ITweetDayRepository _tweetDayRepository;

    public TweetsController(ITweetDayRepository tweetDayRepository)
    {
        //Implementation here
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTweetDay()
    {
            var tweet = await _tweetDayRepository.GetTweetOfTheDayAsync(_systemClock.GetToday);

            if (tweet == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError(LoggingEvents.GetItemNotFound, "An error occurred getting tweet with date: {Date}", _systemClock.GetToday);
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok(tweet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(LoggingEvents.GetItemNotFound, ex, "An error occurred getting tweet with date: {Date}", _systemClock.GetToday);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my test case:

```
public class TweetsControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IMemoryCache> _cache;
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<TweetsController>> _logger;
    private readonly Mock<ISystemClockService> _systemClock;
    //private readonly ITweetDayRepository _tweetDayRepository;

    public TweetsControllerTests()
    {
        _cache = new Mock<IMemoryCache>();
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _systemClock = new Mock<ISystemClockService>();
        _logger = new Mock<ILogger<TweetsController>>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetTweetDay_ReturnsOkResult_WithATweetObject()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockRepo = new Mock<ITweetDayRepository>();
        mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetTweetOfTheDayAsync(DateTime.Today))
            .ReturnsAsync(GetTestTweet());

        var controller = new TweetsController(mockRepo.Object, _cache.Object, _logger.Object,
                                                 _systemClock.Object, _mapper.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.GetTweetDay();

        // Assert
        var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkResult>(result);
    }

    private TweetDay GetTestTweet()
    {
        var tweet = new TweetDay()
        {
            Bird = new Bird(),
            BirdId = 0,
            CreationDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 2),
            DisplayDay = new DateTime(2016, 7, 2),
            LastUpdateDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 2),
            TweetDayId = 0
        };

        return tweet;
    }
}
```

Under my setup, I expect the Mock repository to return the TweetDay object intialised in

```
mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetTweetOfTheDayAsync(DateTime.Today))
    .ReturnsAsync(GetTestTweet());
```

I cannot isolate the exact source of the problem.

Am I setting up the Mock repository properly?  Or is the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on shown setup one of you injected mocked dependencies *(I suspect the system clock)*

```
 var tweet = await _tweetDayRepository.GetTweetOfTheDayAsync(_systemClock.GetToday);
```

is not behaving as expected and causing the hard coded `DateTime.Today` expectation to not match and thus return null or a default value different to what was used in the matcher.

You can get around this by loosening the expected match in the target mock

```
mockRepo
.Setup(repo => repo.GetTweetOfTheDayAsync(It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
.ReturnsAsync(GetTestTweet());
```